# fastapi snowflake connection only pulling 1 record

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, fastapi

I am trying to read data from snowflake database using FASTAPI. I was able to create the connection which is able to pull data from snowflake.

The issue which I am facing right now is that I am only getting 1 record (instead of 10 records).
I suspect I am not using correct keyword while returning the data. appreciate any help.

Here is my code :-

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import snowflake.connector as sf
import configparser


username='username_value'
password='password_value'
account= 'account_value'
warehouse= 'test_wh'
database= 'test_db'


ctx=sf.connect(user=username,password=password,account=account,warehouse=warehouse,database=database)

app = FastAPI()
@app.get('/test API')
async def fetchdata():
  cursor = ctx.cursor()
  cursor.execute("USE WAREHOUSE test_WH ")
  cursor.execute("USE DATABASE test_db") 
  cursor.execute("USE SCHEMA test_schema")
  sql = cursor.execute ("SELECT DISTINCT ID,NAME,AGE,CITY FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE AGE > 60")

for data in sql:
  return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `return` in your inner for-loop. This will return the first row encountered.

If you want to return all rows as a list, you can probably do (I'm not familiar with the snowflake connector):

```
return list(data)
```

instead of the `for`-loop, or `sql.fetchall()`.